# Yii2 Add custom query in dataProvider without rewrite query multiple times

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have a query in Model `Autos` `getSpecialItems()` it is used multiple times in project, but i need add in controller to filter $dataProvider.

How make this whitout write  same query again in controller?

**Autos.php**

```
public function getSpecialItems()
    {

        return self::find()->where(['id_category' => 18])->all();
    }
```

**controller.php**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new AutosSearch();

        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        //need add query here
        //$dataProvider->query->$searchModel->getSpecialItems();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add filter in to your `AutosSearch()` model after `validate()`:

```
if (!$this->validate()) {
    // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
    // $query->where('0=1');
    return $dataProvider;
}

// grid filtering conditions you need
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'id_category' => 18,
]);
```

Comment: Leoneco Is it really a good idea?
If I want to use the default search () I will have to rewrite another search ().

Comment: You can create a specific model and inherit it from your base model, and overwrite search method.